# Error "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" in Makefile

Tags: make

I am trying to create a Makefile with two targets: setup and clean. The setup target is supposed to find all the files in the /usr/lib/man-db and copy them to the directory proj/lib.

```
setup:
    files=( $( find /usr/lib/man-db -name "*.so" ) )
    mkdir proj; cd proj; mkdir lib bin
    cd
    cp $HOME/proj/lib "${files[@]}"
clean:
    rm -r proj
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Makefile has two errors:

1. It relies on `bash` (or on a shell with the same array syntax) without setting the `make` variable `SHELL` to `/bin/bash` (or whatever the path is to the shell executable file).
2. It relies on each action being run in the same shell instance.  Usually, each action line is invoked by a *separate* `$SHELL` (`/bin/sh` by default), which means that you can't set a shell variable on one line and then use it on another, or `cd` into one directory and then assume that you're still in the same directory on the next line of the Makefile.

I would probably rewrite the `setup` target as something like

```
setup:
    mkdir -p proj/lib proj/bin
    find /usr/lib/man-db -type f -name '*.so' -exec cp {} proj/lib \;
```

This additionally does not rely on the `bash` shell being the shell used by `make`, and it also corrects the ordering of the arguments to `cp` (you have yours back to front).