# how to include bash indirect variable assignment in Makefile

Tags: bash, make

Indirect variable setting in bash can be done like [so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210424/557041):

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=bar
ind=foo
echo ${!ind}   # prints `bar'
```

Trying to run the same as a (GNU) Makefile recipe

```
# Makefile
test:
    foo=bar
    ind=foo
    echo $$\{!ind\}
    echo $${!ind}
```

both with and without escaping the `{}` characters fails with the following message:

```
foo=bar
ind=foo
echo $\{!ind\}
${!ind}
echo ${!ind}
/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution
/tmp/Makefile:2: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

The problem is probably some missing/wrong escaping of Makefile's special characters.

Or it could be the order/timing of variable expansion, see [make's secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).

Any ideas?

If it matters, this is bash `4.4.12(1)-release` and make `GNU Make 4.1`

Comment: Related: [Error "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" in Makefile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521965/error-bin-sh-1-syntax-error-unexpected-in-makefile)

Comment: Every line in a Makefile is running in a different shell. Setting a shell variable is not preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You guys are just incredible. Less than ten minutes after I posted my question, you led me to the correct solution, which is:

```
# Makefile
SHELL=/bin/bash
test:
    foo=bar; \
    ind=foo; \
    echo $${!ind}
```

Thank you steeldriver, thank you choroba.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. The default shell used for recipes is a `sh`, so you need to use `SHELL=/bin/bash` for the recipe to even understand syntax like `${!ind}`
2. Each line in the recipe is executed by a separate shell, so if you define a variable in a recipe it is lost for the next line of the same recipe. This is solved by a `.ONESHELL` special target

So the working example looks like this:

```
# Makefile
.ONESHELL:
SHELL=/bin/bash
test:
    foo=bar
    ind=foo
    echo $$\{!ind\}
    echo $${!ind}
```

For a more detailed (and official) explanation, go to
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution